# Не проходит 10 тест на acmp (задача 65)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, олимпиада

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; // принятое сообщение
    string n; // количество следующих сообщений
    string m; // следующие сообщения
    int min; // мин. кол-во отличных позиций
    int k; // кол-во сообщений, которые отличаются от s мин. кол-вом позиций
    string index; // их номера

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("INPUT.TXT");

    getline(fin, s); // считываем принятое сообщение
    getline(fin, n); // считываем n
    min = s.length(); // min присваиваем длину строки

    for (int i = 1; fin.peek() != EOF; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, m); // считываем сообщение
        int diff = 0; // количество отличий = 0
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
        {
            if (s[j] != m[j]) // если отличаются
                diff++; // то увеличиваем счетчик
            if (diff > min) break;  
        }

        if (diff < min) // если эта строка отличается на меньшее кол-во позиций
        {
            min = diff; // min присваиваем это кол-во отличных позиций
            k = 1; // k присваиваем 1
            index = "";
            index = to_string(i); // вносим номер в массив
        }

        else if (diff == min) // если нашлось такое же кол-во позиций
        {
            k++; // увеличиваем k
            index = index + " " + to_string(i); // вносим номер в массив
        }
        m = "";
    }

    fin.close();
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");

    fout << k << endl << index; // выводим результат
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Задача: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=65&ins=1#solution

Comment: Это очень, очень важно, что именно десятый тест! Если бы вы еще привели его данные - цены бы вам не было :)

Comment: я не знаю, что это за тест

Comment: @Harry в подобных задачах никто никогда не приводит данные тестов, иначе теряется весь смысл решения

Comment: @andreymal А вы не поняли, что это с моей стороны что-то типа сарказма? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы нажмете ссылку "обсуждение" на странице задачи, то увидите в первом же комментарии, что возможен набор входных данных с `n = 0` и таковой якобы даже присутствует среди тестов. Условие задачи действительно не гарантирует положительности `n`. Ваша программа, очевидно, будет выводить "мусор" для такого случая, ибо вы не инициализируете значение `k` (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcdb82b515a1f084)

Аналогичная проблема вылезет если все сообщения `m` будут отличаться от сообщения `s` во *всех* позициях. Так как вы изначально делаете `min = s.length()`, ветка `if (diff < min)` не выполнится никогда, и переменной `k` никогда не будет присвоено осмысленное значение (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07ace0077df19ec9)

Другие косяки/странности в вашем коде есть, но в лабораторных условиях они мешать не должны.

Answer (score 0):

Лень копаться в вашей программе на ночь глядя. Держите готовое решение...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

size_t diff(const string& a, const string& b, size_t l)
{
    size_t d = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        d += (a[i] != b[i]);
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    size_t n, l, m;
    cin >> s >> n;
    l = m = s.length();
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        string t;
        cin >> t;
        size_t d = diff(s,t,l);
        if (d > m) continue;
        if (d < m)
        {
            m = d;
            v.clear();
        }
        v.push_back(i+1);
    }
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    for(int i: v) cout << i << endl;

}
```

Comment: Здесь спасибо говорят, принимая решение, нажимая птичку и треугольник вверх слева от ответа... Кстати, ужал решение до 283 байт, но уж это точно не расскажу, как :)

Comment: Что-то в вашем случае спасибо сказали -2 баллами :)

Comment: А ведь подставились вы, Остап Ибрагимович... :) Материализовались, так сказать :)

Comment: Неверное руководство по нажимания кнопки :) не зашло..

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Значит, как в том анекдоте - "И ничего тебе, Петька, за это не будет! Ни коня, ни шашки... ни решения..." :) Зато развлечение в воскресный вечер - поиграться.

Comment: @Mikhailo Ага, посмотрели в табличку? :) Ну, это у меня с детства псевдоним. Посмотреть "Кванты" за примерно 1979-80 годы - там среди решивших задачи по физике тоже есть О.Бендер :)

Comment: Хоть немного восстанавливаю справедливость медведю с джоинтом =)